SpringBoot 3.x.x and redis properties
I upgraded from Spring 2.7.18 to Spring 3.3. Locally, I port-forwarded my Redis service and tested it, and everything worked fine. However, it does not work in production.
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-data-redis-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOnCallable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeOn(Mono.java:4618)
    ....


this log doesn't explain the reason behind Unable to connect. Best guess would be to check if production redis is indeed running and is connectable (check with curl for example)

@JAsgarov I lost my error log and only have part of it, but I found the problem and provided the solution in a post.

I found the problem. I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere directly.
 Redis config in Spring 2.x.x like below:
spring:
  redis:
    host: redis-service-name
    port: 6379
    database: 1

but in spring 3.x.x:
spring
  data:
     redis:
       host: redis-service-name
       port: 6379
       database: 1


It's in the Spring Boot 3.0 release notes here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#redis-properties

@ScottFrederick Yes, I did not see it. Thank you for your message
